# String Oblects in Java

Tags: java, string, object

What does following `String` object or instance creation do in Java?
I came across the following line of code in a Java program:

```
String s = new String("Yes");
```

How does it work?
Are both same with following declaration

```
String s = "Yes";
String s = new String("Yes");
```

I'm curious about the use of `new String("Yes")` instead of simply using a string literal like `String s = "Yes"`. What is the difference, and are there specific scenarios where using `new String(...)` is preferred? I'd appreciate any insights or explanations on this matter.

Comment: *usually* you will never need/use/see `new String("Yes");` Literal strings are always stored/retrieved from the string pool, maintained by the `String` class (see the documentation of `String.intern()`.) That means that every time you use the literal `"Yes"`, the same instance is used (like the same memory location.) If you do `new String("Yes")`. a new instance is created, the literal is passed to its constructor, so the new instance will get the same *content* (characters `Y`, `e` and `s`); but it is **not** the same instance as the literal,

Answer (score -1):

Using a string literal like "hello" just tells the jvm to look up any instance of String with that content, and to return it. Explicitly calling the String constructor (and thus making a new instance) bypasses the jvm's string instance cache and makes a new instance of the String, even if a cached instance already exists. Doing this is generally not wanted tho, as there's little to no reason to care about *which* instance of the String you're getting.

Remember the `==` operator? It checks for instance equality, which means that the following code works:

```java
String a = "hello";
String b = "hello"; // asks jvm for any string instance containing "hello", it returns the same as we got in a
print(a == b); // (pseudocode) true, this is the same String instance

a = "hello";
b = new String("hello"); // create a new instance forcefully
print(a == b); // false, b is now a new instance with the same content as a
print(a.equals(b)); // true, the content is still the same
```